# checkboxlist onchange runs before postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a checklistbox inside an updatepanel. I've declared a client OnChange event for it which calls a server method via ajax jquery.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>          
     <asp:CheckBoxList AutoPostBack="true" ID="chlType" runat="server"
         OnChange="checklistChanged(this);">
     </asp:CheckBoxList>               
    </ContentTemplate>       
</asp:UpdatePanel>

 function checklistChanged(checkboxList) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "default3.aspx/chlType_SelectedIndexChanged",
            data: '{checkList : "chlType"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var str = response.d;
                var splitted = str.split(",");
                updateMarkerVisibility(splitted);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
            }
        });
    }
```

but when I change an item of checkboxlist, the last change isn't affected in server code. I think client code runs before postback.
can any one help me please?

Comment: Um.. Client code *always* runs before the postback.

Comment: I don't think OnChange actually works for ASP.NET checkbox lists anyway